# Remove commas post second occurrence of comma only in last line and check for flag

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files in a specified path, in which I want to remove all the `,` post second occurrence of `,` in the last line only, in an efficient way.

I don't want process to read each line, instead just go directly to the last line and remove all `,` post second occurrence of `,`.

Also, I want a check to be made if last line has EOF in it or not; if it is not available, no changes are to be applied, move to next file.

Sample file:

```
A,111,aaa,A    
B,222,bbb,B
X,EOF,,,,x,X
```

Output:

```
A,111,aaa,A
B,222,bbb,B
X,EOF,xX
```

Example:

```
for i in $(ls /mypath/*.csv); do
sed '$s/,$//' < $i  
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for.

> Note: apparently *sed* is not providing the **"-i"** option for all
>   platforms. If this is the case for your platform you have to use a
>   temporary file
>
> Note also (thanks for glenn jackman's comment on this): This might
>   only work for the GNU sed implementation. You might need to adapt the
>   solution for other implementations

```
for i in $(ls /mypath/*.csv); do
  if [[ `tail -n 1 $i | sed -n /EOF/p` != '' ]]; then
    sed  -i '$s/\([,]\)//3g' $i
  fi
done
```

Comment: The `s///3g` behaviour is unspecified for POSIX sed, but GNU sed specifies it: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

Answer (score 0):

Use `head` to copy everything except the last line to a temporary file. Get the last line with `tail`, process it with `sed` and append it to the temporary file. Last but not least, replace the original file with the processed one.

```
for FILE in /mypath/*.csv ;
do
    TMP_FILE="${FILE}.processed"
    head -n "-1" "$FILE" > "$TMP_FILE"
    tail -n "1"  "$FILE" | sed 's/,\+/,/g' >> "$TMP_FILE"
    mv -f "$TMP_FILE" "$FILE"
done
```

There is probably a more efficient inplace solution, but it does the job.